# Windows 10 can't eject USB drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive

I have multiple thumbdrives and external disks, some protected by Bitlocker and some not.  None of them will ever cleanly eject from my personal Windows 10 x64 laptop.

I've tried just about all of them in my Windows 7 x64 work machine and they have always ejected fine from there.  If on my personal Windows 10 x64 machine, I right-click on the Safely Remove Hardware Eject Media icon in the system tray and I get the message:

---

### Problem Ejecting USB Mass Storage Device

### Windows is unable to stop the device 'USB Mass Storage Device'. Don’t remove this device while it is still in use. Close any programs using this device and then remove it.

### OK

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Asking "Ideas?" is not a good question. That typically results in lots of suggestions, but not always an answer.

Comment: Do you have Write Caching enabled and run Taskmgr while you try to eject the drives?